# How can I tell NLog to selectively log to two different memory targets?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I have a class with an NLog MemoryTarget.
I have the need for each instance of the class that the logs from that instance goes to its MemoryTarget aggregated instance.

I use SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(instance.MemoryTarget, LogLevel.Trace) to initialise the logger, which causes the last ConfigureForTargetLogging call on the last instance to direct all logging to the last instance's MemoryTarget.

The MemoryTarget can be instantiated with a name, but I'm not sure I have a way to create a logger instance that sends to that named target only.

Comment: See the NLog Wiki for how to register two targets with their individual logging targets: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#configure-nlog-targets-for-output

Comment: I added example in my answer. See Perf logger. If you provide your code I can modify answer to match your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logger name filters in rules:
Do not forger final keyword that quit processing any further rule when this one matches:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="perf" xsi:type="File" fileName="perf.log" />
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="Perf" minlevel="Info" writeTo="perf.log" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Programmatically:

```
var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget() { FileName = "perf.log", Name = "perf" };
var console = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget() { Name = "console" };

config.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("Perf", LogLevel.Info, perf)){Final="true"};
config.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, console));

NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

in your code you can get named logger:

```
Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Perf")
```